# Stop contenteditable splitting elements or adding "br" in "pre" tag and replacing it with new line "\n"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There are so much trouble with my `contenteditable` when I put it in a `<pre>` tag.

In a pre tag (by definition) the code has to be "preformatted", so must not be splitted in portions.

But if I edit the code in a div with attribute `contenteditable` the code is splitted in parts or there's a `br` element added.

Example (if you start with something like this):

```
<div class="ce" contenteditable="true">
<div>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
<div>
<pre><code>code</code></pre>
</div>
</div>
```

After editing the code will be:

```
<div class="ce" contenteditable="true">
<div>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
<div>
<pre><code>code<br>dcsdc<br>sdc<br>sdc<br>sdc<br></code></pre>
</div>
</div>
```

And it should to be

```
<div class="ce" contenteditable="true">
<div>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
<div>
<pre><code>code
dcsdc
sdc
sdc
sdc</code></pre>
</div>
</div>
```

I don't have tried with something special, but using the code below doesn't work well

```
$(document).on('keydown','.ce',function(e){
    if ($(this).length) {
        pre = $(this).find("pre");
        if (pre.length) {
            code = pre.find("code");
            if (code.length) {
                    code[0].addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
                        console.log('In ', e.target)
                        if (e.keyCode === 13) { console.log('Return pressed');
                            document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, "\n");
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How to prevent this and leaving "pure" the code in pre tag (whithout using a textarea)?

Comment: Not an answer, but I'd advise avoiding contenteditable and just using a textarea.

Comment: @Emanresu a "*Not an answer, but I'd advise avoiding contenteditable and just using a textarea.*" I thinked it. But there's also so much code that should be displayed like preview and the `contenteditable` it's more comfortable